# Error when running python-openzwave example

Tags: python, python-2.7, z-wave

I'm getting the following error when i try running the built in example in python-openzwave:

```
******* Waiting for network to become ready : 
..python: ../../src/Manager.cpp:320: OpenZWave::Driver* OpenZWave::Manager::GetDriver(uint32): 
Assertion `0' failed. Aborted**
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this was happening since the openzwave-control-panel was already running. The example in Python-openzwave attempts to start a new zwave network while a zwave network is already running(the one the openzwave-control-panel queries for nodes). So the solution is to stop the openzwave control panel if its running and even the openzwave example if you were running it.